# How to programmatically make keyboard textfield open

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I was wondering if it was possible in flutter to programatically open up the keyboard as well as have the cursor and the textfield ready type straight away.

I already know how to pull up the keyboard
`FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());`

But I also need to know how to make the textfield ready to type without the users having to tap the textfield.
as in

Lets say I have a textfield:

```
TextField(
  controller: textEditingController,
);
```

I would like to use code to the effect below so that the user dons't have to tap the textfield

```
textEditingController.openTextField()//Pseudo code
```

: Edit -----------------------------------

Bit bad of me but I forgot to add the focus node as a parameter on the textfield

Within your class add

> final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

then add to textfield

```
TextField(
  ...
  focusNode:_focusNode,
  ...
);
```

then call it by running

```
_focusNode.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to define **FocusNode** variable and assign it to your **TextField** like this :

```
//in header class
FocusNode focusNode  = FocusNode ();

//in build method
TextField(focusNode: focusNode,)
```

Then use this code:

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
```

Comment: Hi I was wondering if you could have a look at my edits on the posts to see if my explanation makes it clearer. My aim is for the user not to have to tap the textfield to then enter text.

Comment: You can use this code where you want it, for example after a timer or when opening a page etc.

Comment: But the user still has to tap the textfield even if the keyboard is up to enter text

Answer (score 2):

full code below, this code make `TextField` focused and opens the keyboard

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen());
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _focusNode.requestFocus();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextField(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        controller: _controller,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you shorten your answer so that it basically say remember to add focus node to your textfield parameter so it doesn't have the full worked example

Answer (score 0):

`StatefulWidget` will come to rescue. `WidgetsBinding` have `addPostFrameCallback()` method that will be called once Widget `Build()` is peformed. so inside `initState()` we can do magic with it

**With nextFocus:**

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
    });
  }
```

**TextField Code:**

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: TextField(),
      ),
```

**With FocusNode :**

```
 FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
    });
  }
```

**Use:**

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: TextField(
          focusNode: focusNode,
        ),
      ),
```

**Output:**

[image]